# What exactly means centipawns field in stockfish/uci output?

Tags: engines, stockfish, uci

According to [this page](http://wbec-ridderkerk.nl/html/UCIProtocol.html):

```
cp 
        the score from the engine's point of view in centipawns.
```

but is it a score for the current (start) position of the game that I feed to engine, or it is a difference between start and final(when coputations completed and best line found) scores?

And the range in which this value varies is unclear to - how could it be as big as 6000 that I sometimes get for my positions? That would be a ton of figures:)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's the score of the *current* position, but it is computed by static evaluation (i.e. counting pieces, pawns, pawn structure, king safety, mobility, etc.) of positions arising in the program's search tree, and applying the [minimax algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimax#Minimax_algorithm_with_alternate_moves) and [alpha-beta pruning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha%E2%80%93beta_pruning).

A cp-score of 6000 does indeed mean the engine thinks it's 60 pawns (centi means 1/100) = between 6 and 7 queens ahead. Because it wasn't able to find a forced mate, it will just try to get the highest possible point advantage, knowing that this will bring the game closer to mate. In practice, a score of (+/-)150 is already decisive most of the times.

Comment: `A cp-score of 6000 does indeed mean the engine thinks White is 60 pawns ahead` I'm confused - if positive scores mean white is winning, doesn't this answer contradict another of your answers? https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/21845/why-does-stockfish-give-a-negative-score-in-a-theoretical-win-for-white/21846#21846

Comment: @NickODell good question - I must've mixed it up with (older?) engines who always display the score from White's point of view.

Comment: The centipawns rating is somewhat arbitrary as engines for a long time don't consider only material, and no engine rates a pawn exactly 100 cp. So it's better to think about it as approximate score that's not consistent between engines either.